# Background-color not applying to child elements of a flex navbar

Tags: css, reactjs

Have a parent Nav with 2 divs inside, Background color of nav does not apply to them

[What entire page looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZV3u.png)
[What navbar looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVCtX.png)

```
export default function Header(){
    return(        
        <nav className='nav'>
            <img src={react} alt="React"/>
            <div className='facts'>ReactFacts</div>
            <div className='course'>React Course - Project 1</div>
        </nav>
    )
}
```

```
nav{
    background-color: #21222A;
    display: flex;   
    align-items: center;
    height: 91px;
    padding: 20px 25px;
      
}

nav > img{
    height: 40px;   
    
}

.facts{   
    margin-left: 12px;
    font-size: 22.2535px;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: -0.05em;
    color: #61DAFB;    

}

nav .course{
    margin-left: auto;
    color: #DEEBF8;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 16px;     
   
}
```

I applied the background color property specifically to both the divs and it worked, but im sure thats just a temporary workaround and would like a more permanent solution

Comment: `background-color` is not inherited - if you want it to inherit then you need to set it to inherit.  but surely you should see the parent background colour behind the children so why do you need to set it - unless you have some other style setting the value for the child?

Comment: If you [look at this](https://jsfiddle.net/4hyuoq8j/) your code works just fine so you must have something else adding a different background colour to your child element

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the `display: flex`; from the `nav element` and use a class on the child elements like `nav-item` and set the background-color on it.

```
nav-item{
background-color: #21222A;
}
```